# Is polynomial evaluation injective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $K$ be an infinite field, and $P\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ non-zero (i.e. $P=\sum k_\alpha x^\alpha$ with $x^\alpha=x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ and one coefficient $k_\alpha\in K$ is non-zero).

> > Is there $\bar a\in K^n$ such that $P(\bar a)\neq 0$ ?

I can do $n=1$...

Comment: Well this amounts to asking wether the (additive) map mapping an abstract polynomial $P$ to its evaluation $K^n\rightarrow K,\ \bar x\mapsto P(\bar x)$ has a kernel. It is injectivity to me. Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: @Arthur, I guess we are not talking about the same map. I am speaking of the evaluation map, and you are talking about the map $\bar x\mapsto P(\bar x)$.

Comment: @Arthur it is about whether the map that associates to a polynomial the corresponding *polynomial function* is injective or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: do it by induction. Prove that if $P$ is a polynomial on an infinite integral domain that has infinitely many roots, then $P=0$.